# Set maximum quantity limit per product to be added in cart

Tags: php, magento

I want user to add only 9 quantity per item. I want to apply this on cart. Maximum qty to each product not whole cart. I have tried but it only applies on whole cart not on each items.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from product attribute  `"Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart"`(max_sale_qty attribute of  product inventory type).
For this going to admin>Catalog >Managed product >Select a product  goes it inventory tab

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but it doesnt work for me.when I put 9 in quantity and add to cart and when I come back to that product and add 3 more cart gets updated to 12. but I dont want to do that user can not add 3 more after 9

Comment: Indexing  from Index Management

Comment: sorry to say but still the same i have tried indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from in System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Product Stock Option -> Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart . This will apply to all products.